# Python: Dictionary in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my program so far.  What I need to do is written in the `docString`.

```
#string, list, list --> Dictionary
def addMovie (title, charList, actList):
    """The function addMovie takes a title of the movie, a list of characters,
    and a list of actors. (The order of characters and actors match one
    another). The function addMovie adds a pair to myIMDb. The key is the title
    of the movie while the value is a dictionary that matches characters to
    actors"""

    dict2 = {}
    for i in range (0, len(charList)):
        dict2 [charList[i]] = actList[i]

    myDict = {title, dict2}
    return myDict
```

The Dictionary `myIMBd` is currently empty.  But what I need help with is the loop.  When I try to do this in the runner.

```
addMovie("Shutter Island", ['Teddy Daniels','Crazy Lady'],['Leodnardo diCaprio', 'old actress'] )
```

I get an error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
addMovie("Shutter Island", ['Teddy Daniels','Crazy Lady'],['Leodnardo diCaprio', 'old actress'] )
File "C:\Python33\makeDictionary.py", line 10, in addMovie
myDict = {title, dict2}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Does that mean that I can't have a dictionary inside of a dictionary?  If so, how do I change it from a dictionary to a non-dict.  If I can have a dict inside a dict, why doesn't this work.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like:

```
myDict = {title: dict2}
```

What you've provided is actually Python's set literal.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a `set`.  Use this instead

```
myDict = {title: dict2}
```

A `dict` in python is not hashable, and the requirement for something to be in a set is that it is hashable (that's how you can quickly tell from the error message what you did wrong). With the commas and no `:`, what you wrote is the `set` literal notation.

Also, `dict` keys must be hashable, but that's not your issue.

Answer (score 1):

this is not `dict`, rather `set`

```
myDict = {title, dict2}
```

You should use colon to create `dict`

```
myDict = {title: dict2}
```

But this exception can be related to `dict` in `dict` too

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

If You try to use `dict` as key of other `dict` or as item of `set` You wil get this error

Comment: No, you can have a dict as a value, you won't get a `TypeError`.

Comment: I haven't written that dict can't be a value of other dict

Comment: Then what are you saying?  You state that putting a dict in a dict will give a `TypeError`, but you are showing putting the second dict as the value of the first (since `title` is a string and is the key).  Since there can only be keys and values in a dict, I was forced to read this as you will get a `TypeError` by putting a dict as the value of a dict.

Comment: If You try to use dict as key of other dict or as item of set You wil get this error

Comment: Ok please feel free to improve my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want :

```
  def addMovie (title, charList, actList):
    dict2 = {}
    myDict={}
    for i in range (0, len(charList)):
        dict2 [charList[i]] = actList[i]
    myDict[title] = dict2
    return myDict

  #printed for testing
  print addMovie("Shutter Island", ['Teddy Daniels','Crazy Lady'],['Leodnardo diCaprio', 'old actress'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you said `,` when you should have said `:`.

Having said that, this version also works, but doesn't require the loop:

```
def addMovie (title, charList, actList):
    return { title : dict(zip(charList, actList)) }
```